# Rotating An Image using AddTemplate

Tags: c#, itext

Using VS 2010, C#, iTextSharp

I am creating a PDF document by opening various existing PDF documents, extracting the Images from them and inserting them into the New PDF document. My problem is that I am trying to Rotate some images in the new PDF Document (depending on Width and Height of the source images) to make the most efficient use of the space in the new PDF document (Ultimately used to print a set of stickers). Looking at the output file the stickers appear to be rotating however, the Right Hand end of the sticker dissapears out of the top of the document resulting in the image appearing to be a large forward slash / from bottom left to the top of the document.

The original code that does not rotate the image (and it works perfectly)

The x,y (sourceXStart, sourceYStart) co-ordinates of the image are dynamically calculated

The existing code - No Rotation - and it works perfectly

```
if ((sourceXStart + pdfInReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1).Width + 10) >= (thePageWidth - 5))
{
    sourceXStart = 5;
    sourceYStart = sourceYStart + lastHeight + 30;
    lastHeight = 0;
}

cb.AddTemplate(page, sourceXStart, sourceYStart);  // Add the image
sourceXStart = sourceXStart + pdfInReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1).Width + 10;
if (pdfInReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1).Width > lastHeight)
{ // Note the maximum height of any sticker in the row
    lastHeight = pdfInReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1).Width;
}
```

The New Code - Attempting Rotation by 90 degreed depending on Width & Height

```
if (pdfInReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1).Width < pdfInReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1).Height)  // Tall Stickers
{ // First we need to check if this image will fit in the width of the page
    if ((sourceXStart + pdfInReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1).Height + 10) >= (thePageWidth - 5))
    {
        sourceXStart = 5;
        sourceYStart = sourceYStart + pdfInReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1).Width + 30;
        lastHeight = 0;
    }

    cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, -1f, 1f, sourceXStart, sourceYStart,    pdfInReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1).Width);
    sourceXStart = sourceXStart + pdfInReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1).Width + 5;
    if (pdfInReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1).Width > lastHeight)
    {
        lastHeight = pdfInReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1).Width;
    }
}
```

Comment: `cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, -1f, 1f, sourceXStart, sourceYStart, pdfInReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1).Width)` does *not* describe a rotation. Could it be you meant parameters like `(page, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, sourceXStart, sourceYStart + pdfInReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1).Width)`?

Comment: mkl - You are an absolute genius. Works perfectly. Many, Many thanks for your input. Appreciated very much